# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused Github action and MySQL

Tags: spring-boot

I'm building my project with Github action using sonar scanner so it fails at connection to database MySQL I tried to change useSSL=true and nothing changed these are the errors I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

I'm using Spring boot with maven multi modules and MySQL as database everything works fine in local and sonar scanner is working fine on sonarcloud but when i try to push the commit to github the action fails at these exceptions I really don't know what's wrong if any suggestions please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your configuration? Is your database server reachable from outside of your network? Can GitHub reach to your database server?

Comment: That point I didn't test, can you tell me how to test if my database reachable or not ?

Comment: Where is your database server installed? Localhost?

Comment: yes on my machine (windows)

Comment: Then GitHub can't connect to your localhost without public IP and further configurations like opening port, giving access privileges  and etc.

Comment: so what should I do now make mysql as docker container ?